# How to pronounce 一 in 他就一本本閱讀 and 他一有空就

Tags: pronounciation

How to pronounce 一 in 他就一本本閱讀 and 他一有空就? I can't differentiate between the first tone, second tone, and fourth tone in this context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

他[tā1]就[jiù4]一[yī1]本[běn3]本[běn3]閱[yuè4]讀[dú2]

他[tā1]一[yī1]有[yǒu3]空[kòng4]就[jiù4]....

For the individual Chinese character, you can check/listen to the pronunciation and tones [here](https://www.zdic.net/hans/%E4%BE%BF).